# $\int_{\alpha} \frac{1}{\sqrt{z}}\ dz$ where $\alpha$ is the semicircle $|z|=1, y\ge 0$

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis

In order to take

$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{z}}\ dz$$

in the contour which is the semicircle $|z|=1, y\ge 0$

I did:

The parametric equation is $\alpha(t) = e^{it}, 0\le t\le \pi$. The integral becomes:
$$\int_0^{\pi} e^{\frac{1}{2}it}ie^{it}\ dt = i\int_0^{\pi} e^{\frac{3}{2}it}\ dt = i\left(-\frac{2}{3i}e^{\frac{3}{2}t}\right)_0^{\pi} = \frac{2}{3}\left(e^{\frac{3}{2}i\pi}-1\right) = -\frac{2}{3}-\frac{2i}{3}$$

However I've seen my friend's answer and he did:

$$\int_{\alpha} \frac{1}{\sqrt{z}}\ dz = \int_0^{\pi} \frac{1}{\sqrt{z}}\ dz = 2\sqrt{z}_{0}^{\pi} = 2\sqrt{\pi}$$

and I can't see what's wrong. Which one is correct?

Comment: You calculated the integral along the semicircle, your friend did it along the real axis between $0$ and $\pi$. Yours is correct

Comment: @caverac but shouldn't only the endpoints matter?

Comment: You guys are using different endpoints: You are using $1$ and $-1$. He's using $0$ and $\pi$